# Unable to create firebase real-time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I deleted a previous project in firebase and created a new one. but I am unable to create a real-time database for it.
I got a null error as shown in the image below. what could be the issue?

I have contacted firebase support but they said they will get back to me in 2 working days.

[image: error message]

Comment: I always recommend trying in an incognito window, with a different browser, and with all browser extensions (specifically things like ad blockers) disabled. Check the JavaScript console output to see if there are any more messages. If this is all it shows, it's unlikely we can do much about it here.

Comment: Trying with a different browser worked just fine. Thank you Frank

Comment: Good to hear. Typically it means your main browser is blocking some data, like an adblocker mistakenly identifying it as ads.